# How to avoid insertion of duplicate records into Database using sqlldr?

Tags: oracle, duplicates, sql-loader

My table has no restrictions to deal with duplicate data. How can I achieve that, no same data is inserted into the table using 'sqlldr' utility? Do I have to make changes in the control file or in the parameters? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with sqlldr alone. One way is to remove duplicates after the load finishes. 
To removing duplicates after sqlldr loads them:

```
DELETE FROM 
  table_name A
WHERE 
  a.rowid > 
   ANY (
 SELECT 
    B.rowid
 FROM 
    table_name B
 WHERE 
    A.col1 = B.col1
 AND 
    A.col2 = B.col2
    );
```

Or you could use external tables for loading the data and just remove duplicates during the load using a query with `distinct` or `group by` clauses, or using a `merge` statement.